# C++11 template function aliases vs wrappers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, alias

Is there any advantage to using the following over the bottom one? And is there any other way to create template function aliases?

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto MakeShared(Args&&... args) -> decltype(std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) 
{
    return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline SharedPtr<T> MakeShared(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::make_shared<T>(args...);
}
```

The last seems more readable to me, and, what's more, Visual Assist highlights the inlined version like a proper function but seems confused about the first (yeah, I know it's a minor point, but still).

What about performance, flexibility, etc?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: How does this make anything more readable o_O? (The obvious advantage of the first version is that it forwards its arguments properly)

Comment: Well, in C++14, you can get rid of the trailing return type and just use `auto`.

Comment: Readable as in from the user perspective, not the creator. T think MakeShared<T>() looks a tad nicer than std::make_shared<T>(), maybe that's just my opinion.

Comment: C++ doesn't exactly have a reputation for readability, especially from the "user" perspective.  Why would a "user" need to read code?  Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: @RobertHarvey that single comment deserves about a thousand up-clicks =P

Comment: Last line: advantages performancewise or otherwise.

Comment: Maybe if you improved your title...  It's a real question if you can summarize it in 15 words or less.

Comment: I cannot determine whether your question is about the specific `SharedPtr<T>` case, or about aliasing templated functions in general. If you mean the former, I would not alias `std::make_shared` because it would mean more "conventions" to learn for the later developer, and more code for everyone to maintain.

Comment: Sorry took out the long-winded talk, and changed the title too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot *alias* functions, you can write new functions that forward the actual work to existing functions, but you cannot just provide aliases.

Now, it is unclear what the real question is. For starters, I would not write wrappers around the standard library features, since that is only making your code more obscure. Wether you like `std::make_shared` better or worse than `MakeShared` or not, the former is well known to any C++ programmer, while the former is something non-obvious that needs to be looked up. (And I personally don't like function names starting with capital letters, but that is a different issue).

If the question is about the implementation, considering that you already know the return type of the wrapper, I would not use decltype, which really makes the code more obscure. But it is still important to use `std::forward`:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> MakeShared(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Adding the trailing return type and the `decltype` when the type is simpler to write and does not depend on the arguments at all is absurdly typing for no reason. The `std::forward` is needed to provide perfect forwarding of the template arguments. Otherwise you might end up calling the incorrect version of the constructor:

```
std::string f();
auto p = std::make_shared<std::string>(f());
    // calls std::string(std::string &&)
auto q = MakeShared<std::string>(f());          // assume no std::forward was used
    // calls std::string(std::string const &)
```

Without the `std::forward` in the implementation of `MakeShared` an rvalue passed as an argument to the function will be forwarded as an lvalue, causing the allocation of a new string, copying data and finally release of the old string at the end of the complete statement. With `std::forward`, the newly allocated `std::string` will *move* out of the argument string.